# Centering one button and placing other buttons to the left and right of that one in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I have a sort of "control panel" that's just a bar with buttons in it. I'd like one button to be in the middle, and the others to be placed on either side of it. They are different sizes, but if necessary, I could make them the same size. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Relevant HTML/CSS:

```
<div id=controls>
        <button type=button class=tools id=save>Download Doodle</button>
        <button type=button class=tools id=clear>Clear Canvas</button>
        <button type=button id=doodle>Doodle!</button>
</div>
```

---

```
/*Control Panel*/
#controls{
  position:relative;
  background-color:black;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:15px 0px;
  z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
}

button{
  display:block;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  width:auto;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 1s;
  background-color:black;
  border:3px solid white;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float:left;
}

.tools{
    display:none;
}

#doodle{
  float:none;
}
button:hover{
  background-color:white;
  color:black;
}

/*End Control Panel*/
```

Comment: What code have you tried, what happens, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: `display:block;` and `float:left;` are your friends.

Comment: Please share a more complete code sample such as HTML and CSS snippets.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I can think of nothing that might work for my situation. I'm kinda completely lost, which is why I'm here. @PHPGlue I've heard about float CSS property, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around it. What does it do and how does it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the float css property to place the element next to each other. You can read about it here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Adjust the margin right to get the appropriate distance.

Hope this helps

```css
button{
float:left;
  background-color:blue;
  border:0;
  color:white;
  margin-right:10%;
  
}
```

```html
  
<button>button 1</button>
<button>button 2</button>
<button>button 3</button>
```

Comment: Note that `<button>` cannot take other Elements within it, in some Browsers. It's really the same as `<input type='button'  />`, as long as you specify that attribute. Just a comment.

Comment: Oh. Thank You ! I didn't Really know that :)

Comment: Yeah, you won't be able to run Events on nested Elements within `<button>` in some Browsers. Just avoid nesting Elements within.

Comment: Thank you very much, @NishaanthKanna I really feel like this will work, but now I can't seem to get them to align center. text-align: center; is not working. Could you check the code I added and see what the problem might be?

Comment: **text-align:center;** will work only for text not for buttons I suppose @ViperZer0